# Anaconda clean command not working properly

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I want to completely uninstall anaconda from my system. So to uninstall Anaconda I followed official docs and run the following commands in my anaconda prompt:

1. `conda install anaconda-clean`
2. `anaconda-clean --yes`

But after running the second command, I got the following error:

```
(base) C:\Users\hp>anaconda-clean --yes
Backup directory: C:\Users\hp\.anaconda_backup\2020-06-02T231530
Error: Unable to move C:\Users\hp\.astropy
Error: Unable to move C:\Users\hp\.conda
Error: Unable to move C:\Users\hp\.condarc
Error: Unable to move C:\Users\hp\.ipynb_checkpoints
Error: Unable to move C:\Users\hp\.ipython
Error: Unable to move C:\Users\hp\.jupyter
Error: Unable to move C:\Users\hp\.matplotlib
```

Has anyone face the similar issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you remove those directories manually?

Comment: Yeah I tried it but it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

nope. The solution is, enter conda first by using **conda activate** line and the type **anaconda-clean --y**, if u want to remove anaconda. But, in order to do that you need to download and install anaconda-clean package first.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the function of this command is to automatically move these configuration files and directories to the backup folder.So if your system is windows, you can move these files manually.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users: try running the command as administrator

```
sudo anaconda-clean --yes
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I guess the only available solution is to move the files manually. Or uninstall anaconda manually from your device.

Answer (score 0):

A simple remove will leave a few files behind, which for most users is just fine.

Windows

1. Open the file explorer.
2. Delete your environment (anaconda3\envs) and package (anaconda3\pkgs) folders in your user folder.
3. Open Add or remove programs and uninstall your Anaconda installation or your version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the anaconda prompt on the windows search bar. Right click on it and select run as administrator. Then the error should go away. Worked for me.